# Sequence of $a_n=(-\frac{1}{2})^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Considering the sequence of $a_n=(-\frac{1}{2})^n$ where n is a natural number, I have to prove that it is a sequence in which the positive terms and negative terms generate two geometric illiminated progressions having the same ratio then calculate the sum of the terms of $a_n$.
The final part is easy but I don't know how to give a demonstration of what the exercise is asking. I can find some terms then take the positive one and the negative one and finally prove that the two sequences I found are two geometric progression having the same ratio... But I find not very elegant... Can you help me please?
Thanks in advance!
(following my solution the ratio is 1/4)

Comment: The positive terms are $(-\frac{1}{2})^{2n}=(\frac{1}{4})^n$. Similarly for the negative terms.

Comment: Just write out some terms, I think it will become clear: $\frac{1}{2^0} - \frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{2^2} - \frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4} - \frac{1}{2^5}+...$ or, if we regroup: $1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^4} + ...$ and $-\left(\frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^5} + ...\right)$ _or_ $\frac{1}{4^0} + \frac{1}{4^1} + \frac{1}{4^2} + ...$ and $-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4^0} + \frac{1}{4^1} + \frac{1}{4^2} +  ...\right)$.

Comment: I just solved it in this way but I find it not so elegant, I wanted another finer way :)

Comment: What's not elegant about $\sum \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n - \frac{1}{2}\sum \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n = \left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\right)\sum \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n = \frac{1}{2}\sum \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n$ which then gives $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{4}} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positive terms go with even $\;n\;$:

$$\left\{\frac1{2^{2n}}\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}=\left\{\frac14\,,\,\frac1{16}\,,\,\frac1{64}\,,\ldots\,,\frac1{4^n}\,,\ldots\right\}$$

The above geometric sequence's constant quotient is

$$\frac{\frac1{4^{n+1}}}{\frac1{4^n}}=\frac14$$

and thus the sum of this series (why does the sum exist?) is

$$\frac{\frac14}{1-\frac1{4}}=\frac13$$

the negative terms with odd $\;n\;$:

$$\left\{-\frac1{2^{2n-1}}\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}=\left\{-\frac12\,,\,-\frac18\,,\,-\frac1{32}\,,\ldots\,,\,-\frac2{2^{2n}}\,,\ldots\right\}$$

and its quotient is

$$\frac{-\frac2{2^{2(n+1)}}}{-\frac2{2^{2n}}}=\frac14$$

and its sum is

$$\frac{-\frac12}{1-\frac14}=-\frac23$$

Comment: There's no way the sum is negative, because we already know the sum equals $\frac{1}{1 - -\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{2}{3}$.  Even if you start at $n = 1$, it's still just $\frac{2}{3} - 1 = -\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @Jared, believe me: if you add negative real numbers you get a negative real number. You should also be more careful before you downjbvote and check what is written: my series begins at $\;n=1\;$ ,unlike the other answer in which it begins at $\;n=0\;$

Comment: Your answer is confusing (sorry, I would have undid my downvote but I can't anymore).  I see it now: $\frac{1}{3} + -\frac{2}{3} = -\frac{1}{3}$.  Also, imo, it's bad practice to reference $\mathbb{N}$ because the set is ambiguous and should not be used.  Some consider the natural numbers to include $0$ (as I do) and some do not.  There's no point in arguing because it's not a universally agreed upon set--in my mind the natural numbers are the counting numbers (which include $0$) but clearly in your mind, the natural numbers are the cardinal numbers.

Comment: (1)About $\;\Bbb N\;$: it's an international symbol for the natural numbers, and reading **with some attention** my answer one can see that in both cases I begin with $\;n=1\;$ the counting, so no confusion here. (2) No need to rush up and downvote others' answer **even** if it seems to be wrong. Sometimes is our own understanding what is impaired (as in this case), other times it may be a typo or a little mistake the answerer can address upon being warned, etc. In the present case you could *also* read the other answer (from another well known member), who also got a negative on the odd Nos.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for every $n\geqslant0$,
$$a_{2n}=r^n,\qquad a_{2n+1}=b\cdot r^n,
$$
with
$$
b=-\frac12,\qquad r=\frac14,$$
hence
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n}=\frac1{1-r}=\frac43\qquad\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n+1}=\frac{b}{1-r}=-\frac23,
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}=\frac43-\frac23=\frac23.
$$